# casperjs catch dynamic content after dynamic click

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I use casperjs scrape urls on *http://testphp.vulnweb.com/AJAX/*,  some urls rely on dynamic click a tags, I use casperjs dynamic click tags but i can't get dynamic content tags after click,

```
page.waitFor(function check(){
    return this.evaluate(function () {
        var elements = __utils__.getElementsByXPath('//a[starts-with(@href, "javascript:")]');
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
            var e = elements[i];
            event = window.__ksevent__.initMouseEvent('click');
            return e.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
    })
}, function then(){
    return this.fireEvent('click', x('//a[starts-with(@href, "javascript:")]'));
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to wait until the element appear?

Comment: yeah,  I added waitFor code but it didn't change the dom

Comment: Clicking in a loop is not that great and you're return in the first iteration. Anyway, the result will probably be always `null` because you cannot pass complex objects out of the page context. Try `return elements.length>0;` instead

Comment: I have confirmed func then() have been executed, but it executed on the origin html, it supposed to be executed on the dynamic html after click